# Specifying application config file by name when Spring Boot starts up

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

Currently I can build my Gradle-based Spring Boot app like so:

```
./gradlew build && java -Dspring.config=. -jar build/libs/myapp.jar
```

And this works fine provided I have an `application.yml` in the root of my project directory.

However, I would now like to have both an `application-local.yml` as well as an `application-dev.yml`, and to specify which one to use when I build + run `myapp.jar`.

**How can I specify either file at startup?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Spring boot's capability of using Profile Specific property file.
You can specify the application yml inline with your profile name
application-[profile].yml. In your case, it would be

```
application-dev.yml
application-local.yml
```

Specify the profile you would want to use as a command line argument

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=dev
```